# How to use scanf() to split the string "127.0.0.1:1024" into "127.0.0.1" and "1024"?

Tags: c, split

So I have a string "`127.0.0.1:1024`"

I want to split the `127.0.0.1` from `1024`. This is what I've tried:

```
char server[2048], port[2048];
int scanErr = sscanf(argv[1], "%[^:]2047s:%2047s", server, port);
```

It gets the `127.0.0.1` right, but port is still empty. What could be the problem?

Comment: I suggest you take some time with e.g. [this `scanf` (and family) reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf). Your format for `%[` is wrong.

Comment: Also, consider `strtok`

Comment: *How to use sscanf...*  I wouldn't.  [The `scanf()` family of functions is horribly difficult](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html) to use without introducing serious bugs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need extra info after `%[]`:

```
sscanf(argv[1], "%15[^:]:%5s", server, port);
```

Plus, I don't really think you need *that* much space for them:

```
char server[16], port[6];
```

Comment: Also I'd scan the port number into an unsigned 16bit integer, not into a string.

Comment: @alk Cool move! But what about the `atol` family?

Comment: Do not use `atoX` family -- it provides absolutely no way to validate a conversion takes place. Use `strtoX` family instead.

Comment: @alk It's likely that OP's next act will be to call `getaddrinfo`, which takes the port as a string, not a number.

Answer (score 3):

This particular task is best performed by [`strsep`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strsep.3.html), not `sscanf`.  (All of the `*scanf` functions are broken-as-specified and should never be used for *anything*.  Yes, really.)  I'd do something like this:

```
char *server_with_port, *server, *port, *p;

server_with_port = strdup(argv[1]); // writable copy required
if (!server_with_port) {
    perror("strdup");
    return 1;
}

p = server_with_port;
server = strsep(&p, ":");
port = strsep(&p, ":");
if (!server || !port || p) {
    fprintf(stderr, "%s: could not parse '%s'\n", argv[0], argv[1]);
    usage(argv[0]);
    return 1;
}

// now use 'server' and 'port'
// free only 'server_with_port' when finished
```

`strsep` is a BSD extension which most modern Unixes provide.  If you don't have it, `strtok_r`, part of the 1999 C standard, provides the same functionality with a clunkier interface.  If you don't have *that*, `strtok`, part of the original C standard, provides the same functionality but with an even clunkier and non-thread-safe interface.

`strdup` is also originally a BSD extension but was standardized in POSIX.1-2001.